# regex to replace based on specific last character

Tags: python, regex

I've below string in, here PT is pacific time, could other zone too. Number, hours and mins are more important in this text

```
PT45M
PT1H
PT30M
PT
PT2H
```

here last character is either M or H, that means hour or minute. And if nothing is present (PT), then it means its 0

how can get this output like below

```
45
60
30
0
120
```

getting confused with how to check all required checks in single regex

```
1 - check if it is having right pattern (PT<AnyNumber><H|M>)
2 - If yes, then check if last character is H or M
3 - if its H, then multiple by 60
4 - if point 1 is false, then return 0
```

any suggestions please

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Why use regex? You could do this without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern `PT(\d+)([HM])` ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uecIvq/1)):

```py
import re

test_cases = ["PT45M", "PT1H", "PT30M", "PT", "PT2H"]

pat = re.compile(r"PT(\d+)([HM])")

for t in test_cases:
    out, m = 0, pat.match(t)
    if m:
        out = int(m.group(1)) * (60 if m.group(2) == "H" else 1)
    print(t, out)
```

Prints:

```
PT45M 45
PT1H 60
PT30M 30
PT 0
PT2H 120
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably has its weaknesses, but this is the solution I just came up:

```
import re

times = ["PT45M", "PT1H", "PT30M", "PT", "PT2H"]

check_format_1 = r"(PT)(\d{0,2})([HM]{0,1})(\d{0,2})([HM]{0,1})"

for string in times:
    res = re.match(check_format_1, string)
    hours = (
        res.group(2)
        if res.group(3) != "M"
        else res.group(4)
        if res.group(5) != "M" and res.group(3) != "H"
        else "0"
    )
    if len(hours) == 0:
        hours = "0"

    minutes = (
        res.group(2)
        if res.group(3) != "H"
        else res.group(4)
        if res.group(5) != "H" and res.group(3) != "M"
        else "0"
    )
    if len(minutes) == 0:
        minutes = "0"

    print("-----")
    print(string)
    print(f"{hours} hours")
    print(f"{minutes} minutes")
    print(f"Total {int(minutes) + int(hours) * 60} minutes")
```

It returns this output:

```
-----
PT45M
0 hours
45 minutes
Total 45 minutes
-----
PT1H
1 hours
0 minutes
Total 60 minutes
-----
PT30M
0 hours
30 minutes
Total 30 minutes
-----
PT
0 hours
0 minutes
Total 0 minutes
-----
PT2H
2 hours
0 minutes
Total 120 minutes
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
import re
l1 = ['PT45M', 'PT1H', 'PT30M', 'PT', 'PT2H']
l2 = [eval(s[2:].replace('M','').replace('H','*60')) if re.match(r'^PT\d+[HM]$', s) else 0 for s in l1]
print(l2)
```

Prints:

```
[45, 60, 30, 0, 120]
```

---

- Loop all elements in an array using list comprehension;
- Check if the elements match the pattern `^PT\d+[HM]$`;
- If a match occurs then take substring from 3rd character onwards, replace 'M' with empty string and 'H' with '*60';
- The result of the above is then calculated with `eval()` to return correct results;
- If no match occurs return 0.
- `